# Why Space Indent less than 8 is not detected by Git with indent-with-non-tab checking enabled?

Tags: git

I find that when I enabled `indent-with-non-tab` in Git, if I use a 4 (or whatever less than 8) space indent, Git will not mark it red in `git diff`, but when I use 8 (or more than 8) space indent, Git will mark it red as expected.

I'm using `git version 2.5.1.windows.1`.

My git config is here:

```
git config --global core.whitespace trailing-space,space-before-tab,-cr-at-eol,indent-with-non-tab,-tab-in-indent
```

And following is my test file `bad-space-example.txt`:

```
hello
    tab indent
       space indent
     tab indent with following space
    space before tab
    space at eol (trailing-space) 
    tab at eol (trailing-space) 
    blank at eof (also trailing-space)
```

My Question is:

1. Why this happens, is it on purpose or it is a bug?
2. How to tell Git that 4-space-indent is also need to be marked?

Comment: As noted in the `git config` documentation, the default tab width is "every 8th column". Four spaces is therefore *required* for a four-space indent, because a tab would take you to column 9, not column 5 (column 1 being the first column). You can override Git's default tabwidth.

Comment: The `tabwidth` option is only mentioned [here](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration), and I can't search more about it or how to config it, can you help?

Comment: I find it [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) via google the keyword "tabwidth" quoted, thx!  And I think you should post your comment as an answer, since it solved my problem well.